# Assign formulas to filled lines

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Sheets:
Hello friends. I use the following script in my table. Paste the formula below into cell T2. Then it pastes the formula in cell T2 to the range T2: T100. Can I translate this process to this?
If there is a value in the range A2: A100, apply the formula to the T column at that value.
for example

```
             A                                            T
1
2           XYZ                                         Formula
3
4
```

```
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var rr = event.source.getRange('T2');
    rr.setFormula('=IFERROR(IF(G2<>0;IF(ARRAYFORMULA(LARGE(IF(matbaaya_giden!B:B=B2;matbaaya_giden!G:G;"");1))=G2-1;ARRAYFORMULA(LARGE(IF(matbaaya_giden!B:B=B2;matbaaya_giden!G:G;"");1)) & ". Baskı ✓";"Baskıyı Kontrol Ediniz.");"");"")');


     var oneRowCopy = s.getRange(2,20);
  var targetRows = s.getRange(3,20,100);
  oneRowCopy.copyTo(targetRows);
```

Comment: please reword your questions for better understanding

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, as well as the outcome you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with the code below. Thank you.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  // check Ax for any truthy value
  if (e.range.offset(0, 1 - col).getValue()) {
    e.range.offset(0, 5 - col, 1, 1).setValue("dolu");
  }
  else
  {
    e.range.offset(0, 5 - col, 1, 1).setValue("boş");

  }
}
```